# How to make a video from separate frames

Tags: video-editor, blender, editing

I used blender to create an animation, and i set the output to PNG. So i it is easier to analyse the animation. Now i want to turn those 180 png frames into a video. This is something that can be done with Movie Maker on windows. Is there software on Ubuntu to do this?

Thank you

Comment: for command line see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/269834/how-to-generate-a-mov-file-from-png-images (you can choose a video format other than MOV of course)

Answer (score 0):

You can use blender which includes it's own Video Sequence Editor. Within the VSE when you add an image you can select as many images as you want and they will be added as a sequence. Then you can select a video format for the output file format adjust the encoding settings to taste and render the animation.