# Converting png files to a movie?

Tags: command-line, video-conversion

I've been trying to make a movie using a bunch of png files, however without any success. The following command

```
convert -delay 100 -loop 0 *.png animation.mpeg
```

yields

```
convert.im6: delegate failed `"ffmpeg" -v -1 -mbd rd -trellis 2 
-cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -i "%M%%d.jpg" "%u.%m" 2> "%Z"' @ 
error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1065.
```

The odd thing is that I am successfully be able to make a gif using the following command

```
convert -delay 100 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: similar http://askubuntu.com/questions/269834/how-to-generate-a-mov-file-from-png-images and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315192/avconv-make-a-video-from-a-subset-on-images and http://superuser.com/questions/621033/using-ffmpeg-to-make-a-movie-from-png-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a video file from a set of jpg images?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/610903/how-can-i-create-a-video-file-from-a-set-of-jpg-images)

Comment: Not quite an exact duplicate, but I asked almost the same thing but with jpg files - http://askubuntu.com/questions/610903/how-can-i-create-a-video-file-from-a-set-of-jpg-images

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [create slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images). Their suggestion is to use "libx264" for better quality. The images need a sequence number (could that be your problem?)

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i *%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

(here %03 means a 3 digit numbering).

Comment: ***4*** digits in your file name? and are they in sequence? If not you need to supply all the files (dont use wildcards)

Comment: can I use the same exact command to convert to avi format or do I have to add additional parameters?

Comment: You can use this. Just add the output to it as your aci